# Build Jmeter JMX file using JAVA for parallel load with different set of data

Tags: java, jmeter, performance-testing

I'm trying to build the `JMX` file for `JMETER` through Java to keep in inline with my service automation framework. Ultimately i do not want to use `JMETER` UI to avoid rework on the request generation. Partially i have succeeded in the same but the problem is i'm not able to create a `JMX` file which can work with multiple input.

Generally, this is achieved in `JMETER` UI by using `CSV` data set config. Can someone help me in achieving the parallel request load with varying data from `CSV` using `JAVA`?

Please find below the sampler code that i'm using now.

```
examplecomSampler.setName("Test");
examplecomSampler.setDomain("SampleDomain");
examplecomSampler.setPort("Sample Port");
examplecomSampler.setPath("Sample Path");
examplecomSampler.setMethod("Test");
examplecomSampler.setProtocol("https");
examplecomSampler.addNonEncodedArgument("",strJson , "");
examplecomSampler.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, HTTPSamplerProxy.class.getName());
examplecomSampler.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, HttpTestSampleGui.class.getName());
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can help you to achieve this in `JMETER` with `JAVA`.

[`CSV DATA SET CONFIG`](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) can be `ADDED` just the `SAME` way you did with [`HTTP REQUEST`](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler

The relevant `CLASS` is [CSVDataSet](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/config/CSVDataSet.html). If you need an `EXAMPLE` in `JAVA` here is `SOME` reference `CODE`

```
CSVDataSet csvDataSet = new CSVDataSet();
csvDataSet.setName("CSV Data Set Config");
csvDataSet.setProperty("delimiter",",");
csvDataSet.setProperty("filename","/path/to/your/file.csv");
csvDataSet.setProperty("fileEncoding","UTF-8");
csvDataSet.setProperty("ignoreFirstLine",false);
csvDataSet.setProperty("quotedData",false);
csvDataSet.setProperty("recycle",true);
csvDataSet.setProperty("shareMode","shareMode.all");
csvDataSet.setProperty("stopThread",false);
csvDataSet.setProperty("variableNames","your_variable_name");
csvDataSet.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS,CSVDataSet.class.getName());
csvDataSet.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS,TestBeanGUI.class.getName());
```

More information: [Five Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui)

Comment: Thanks a ton for the response. Just another question in continuation with the same topic. Can i add this csvDataSet directly to my sampler also how can i parameterize my input JSON with the values in the csv?